# Can I get terrain data from anywhere for use in simulations?

Tags: google-maps, simulation, geography

Is there a way I can build terrain data in a simple way from sources like Google Maps. I am not interested in heights but a simple 2D representation will be good enough.

For instance, I am trying to represent a terrain using the roads and buildings inside a map to model a traffic simulation. Representing objects like buildings is necessary so that when my cars are moving on a road, they should know when to take a turn etc. Are there any standards for representing these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are dozens of map standards. also map data tends to be very expensive, although there are some low cost and open source map sources. Eg. OpenStreetMap, and for the US, Tiger/Line.

I would also read up on, at least, some introductory GIS - I think you'll find the field is much bigger and more complex that you are initially thinking.